# mvnpdf behavior weird at infinity

Tags: matlab, probability-density

The mvnpdf function in Matlab takes the default mean and std as 0 and I (Identity matrix).

When I type this:

```
mvnpdf([0,0])
ans = 0.1592  
mvnpdf([0,0], [0,0], [1,0;0,1])
 ans = 0.1592  
 mvnpdf([1,1])
 ans =  0.0585
 mvnpdf([1,1], [0,0], [1,0;0,1])
 ans = 0.0585
```

So the function works when we specify the Mean and Correlation Matrix outselves, however, when I do this, it no longer works

```
mvnpdf([Inf,Inf])
ans = 0
 mvnpdf([Inf,Inf], [0,0], [1,0;0,1])
ans = NaN
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

These bivariate normal pdfs are a small part of a larger expression which I am optimizing over "rho", so I need an expression like

```
   mvnpdf([Gamma(i+1) Tau(j+1)],[0 0],[1,rho;rho 1])
```

to work for some unkown $\rho$ and in additional inputs $\Gamma$ and $\Tau$ which can possible be $\infty$ or $-\infty$. Ok LaTeX doesnt seem to work.

Anyway, I would like to be able to provide a correlation Matrix with an unknown parameter Rho and additional inputs Gamma's and Tau's which may run over a large range and could possibly be negative or positive infinity.

Comment: Odd behavior indeed! Assuming that `mvnpdf` is zero, you could check if your input vector is infinity, like so: `if any(isinf([ Gamma(i+1) Tau(j+1) ]));pdfVal = 0; else; pdfVal = mvnpdf([Gamma(i+1) Tau(j+1)],[0 0],[1,rho;rho 1]); end;`

Comment: @kedarps Thanks so much! I'll implement your code! Cheers!